# String to Hex value conversion in C++

Tags: c++, c

Is there a way where a couple of integers put into a string(by concatenation) and when that string is read character by character and printed as hex, the hex values of those numbers are equivalent to numbers themselves.

Example:

- Lets say i have two numbers, 6 and 8 and a string "yahoo".
- In the first step, i concatenate them and get a single string 
  "6yahoo8" using `snprintf()`.
- In the next step, i read that string character by character and print
  out their hex values,
- i want to obtain final output as:

  {0x06, 0x79, 0x61, 0x68, 0x6F,
         0x6F, 0x08}.
- But my program is printing the result:

  {0x36, 0x79, 0x61, 0x68, 0x6F,
  0x6F, 0x38}.

  This result is correct except first and last byte.
  Any ideas how to accomplish the task like i wanted to?
  Advice is very much appreciated.

  The program i am using to form the string:

  ```
  string encode_url() {
      StringAccum sa;
      string url;
      const char *str = "yahoo";
      int p = 6;
      int q = 8;
      sa.snprintf(1,"%x", p);   // snprintf(len, format, value);
      sa << str.c_str();
      sa.snprintf(1, "%x", q);
      url = string(sa.take_string().c_str());
      return url;
  }
  ```

  There are some customary functions that we use like StringAccum, which is basically String Accumulator in C++.

Comment: Please stop using the term "C/C++".

Comment: @NickyC I had put a better version of the same, :P

Comment: when you put number into string it becomes a char, and ASCII code for '6' is 36.

Comment: It is not clear what "this task" is. If it's making the equality `'6' == 6` hold, then no, there's no way.

Comment: Do not use `snprintf`.

Comment: The reason behind why you need this is absolutely vexing me. It has the pungent aroma of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Regardless, If you want to store a (very range-limited) number at the beginning or end of your `char` buffer, don't convert it; just store it directly in the appropriate character slot (i.e. don't use `snprintf`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Okay, you win.

Answer (score 0):

To find the reason you have to look into ASCII character codes.

if you convert the 8 in hexadecimal you will get 0x38. similar for 6 you will get 0x36.

why did you get 0x38 instead of 0x8 because here 8 is a string not a character variable (A bit less obvious than int is the other of the plain integral types, the char. It's basically just another sort of int, but has a different application).